# Compare strings by custom sort order

Tags: optimization, algorithm, vb.net

Each letter represent a category. Example the group with "M" Code is greater Than "I" and "C" group. "F" is the higher group

Here is what I did but I wonder if there is a better way to do it.

```
 Private Function CompareCode(ByVal code As String, ByVal otherCode As String) As Boolean
    Dim orderedCode As New List(Of String)
    orderedCode.Add("I")
    orderedCode.Add("C")
    orderedCode.Add("M")
    orderedCode.Add("F")

    Return orderedCode.IndexOf(code) < orderedCode.IndexOf(otherCode)

End Function
```

Comment: Would you mind to add a little bit of context about what this method should do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Naming**

The name `CompareCode` does not express ll what this method is doing. Try to name it more meaningful.

**General**

You don't need a `List(Of String)` here. Add a private const string like

```
Private Const orderedCode As String = "ICMF"
Private Function CompareCode(ByVal code As String, ByVal otherCode As String) As Boolean
    Return orderedCode.IndexOf(code) < orderedCode.IndexOf(otherCode)
End Function
```

Comment: If for some reason he *must* use a `List(Of String)`, this might be cleaner: `Dim orderedCode As New List(Of String) From { "I", "C", "M", "F" }`.

Comment: I agree with the problem of method name. thx

Comment: @Abbas I would agree, about some reason...,  if the List had been declared outside of the method.

Comment: The list is not required and is a big part of the reason I'm asking for a better way.

Comment: Then you should indeed never use a List and use the solution @Heslacher provided.

Comment: As always this comunity is helpful, quick and not judging. Thank you